# Calculatewith String of android

Tags: java, android, string, int

I have a

```
String id = "1";
String id2 = " 5";
```

How can i calculate

```
String sum = id + id2 + "2";
```

How can i sum it and give result = 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the relevant [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), (Oracle). You need to call `Integer.parseInt("num")`, to make your code work. It should look like this:

```
int sum = Integer.parseInt(id) + Integer.parseInt(id2) + Integer.parseInt("2");
```

Running an outputting its value using `System.out.println()`, you get:

```
8
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i have resolved that problem but i can't give a "Like"

Comment: Yes you can, click the green checkmark icon(currently grey) next to one of the answers to mark it correct

Answer (score 1):

Using native Java. Use `Integer.parseInt()` or `Integer.valueOf()`. For example,

```
int sum = Integer.parseInt("9") + Integer.parseInt("7");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you don't have access to modify the String class and even if you did I do not believe you can override an operator in Java.

What you can do is create a static method:

```
public class StringUtils {
    public static String ParseAdd(String... numStrings) {
        int output = 0;
        for (String numString : numStrings)
            output += Integer.parseInt(numString);
        return output + "";
}
```

then you can do:

```
String id = "1";
String id2 = " 5";

String sum = StringUtils.ParseAdd(id, id2, "2");
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i have resolved that problem but i can't give a "Like"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert String into Integer before calculating sum, and again convert it back to String if you want output in String.

You can use *Integer.parseInt(string)* to convert **String -> Integer**.

After addition, 
you can use *String.valueOf(integer)* to convert **Integer -> String**.

```
    String id = "01";
    String id2 = "05";

    int amount = Integer.parseInt(id) + Integer.parseInt(id2) + Integer.parseInt("2");
    String sum = String.valueOf(amount);
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i have resolved that problem but i can't give a "Like"

Answer (score 0):

```
int sumInt = Integer.parseInt(id) + Integer.parseInt(id2) + Integer.parseInt("2");
String sum = String.vlaueOf(sumInt)
```

Here sum is "8" or whatever is need as per values of id and id2.

Comment: Thank you so much , i have resolved that problem but i can't give a "Like"

Comment: Okay.. No Issues. My answer was not expecting "like". Main concern was to provide you solutions :)